# No Item Menu in NotEnoughItems mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I can't find the item menu (right of the screen) in the NotEnoughItems mod, and the O key won't help, neither does the GUI Setting work. It only shows up when I open up a the potion maker, recipe for a item, crafting profiling, etc, but the menu disappears after I try t get to my inventory. Please help me.

Comment: Nvm found out...

Comment: Please post your fix so others can benefit too.

Comment: I found out any gamemode other than creative gives you the menu.

Comment: Then post it in answer so others can benefit too

Answer (score 0):

I found out that every gamemode other than creative (survival, adventure, and creative+) have the item menu, but I have no idea how to get it into creative mode.